# Group footer subtraction

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a newbie i want to know how you can subtract GF2 values one after the other .I have 4 new sub heading i need to create,for example 
`GF2.A-GF2.B = Gross profit 
GF2.B-GF2.C = Operating profit 
GF2.C-GF2.D = Profit before tax 
GF2.D-GF2.E = Net profit` 
and how do you alternate the contents of label in GF1 like Gross profit ,Operating profit,Profit before tax and Net profit to show when needed.Dynamically

Comment: What kinds of fields are we working with here (meaning, what are fields A, B, and so on)? Also, I don't understand what you mean by "how do you alternate the contents of label in GF1...to show when needed dynamically?"

Comment: sorry for getting back to you late @Ryan . Field A is a sum function of a group. the sum value is grouped by the name of a *balance sheet* heading. Cost of sales -turnover = gross profit .so turnover has a value and cost of sales , next calculation will take the next heading which will look like this operating cost -gross profit =operating profit. the value gross profit from above should be retained so we can subtract it with next sum grouped heading. then Non operating income - operating profit = Profit before tax. so the value in operating profit must be retained to subtract the next heading

Answer (score 0):

In formulas in the group footer of your balance sheets, you can refer to the summary values like this: `sum({table.ThingToSum},{table.ThingYouGroupOn}`. So that would be like your "Field A". So, to get Gross Profit for example, you could you could create a group footer formula like this: `sum({table.colA},{table.balanceSheet}) - sum({table.colB},{table.balanceSheet})` where colA and colB are the two fields you were summarizing before.

To get your Net Profit, you could refer back to the result of the formula you made above with something like this `{@Gross Profit} - sum({table.colC},{table.balanceSheet})`. If {table.colC} holds, say, taxes or other deductions.